# Unable to create APK when using ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard, android-multidex

I suddenly started getting the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` error when trying to create an apk. I didn't want to use the fix of increasing the HeapSize.. so I thought I'd try using ProGuard in the hopes it will help.

However, when I enable proguard :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

and try to create an apk, I get these errors :

[image]

I tried editing the 'proguard-rules.pro' like this :

```
-dontwarn class com.facebook.** { *; }
-dontwarn class com.appsflyer.** { *; }
-dontwarn class org.joda.time.** { *; }
```

but it just invokes errors such as :

```
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Unknown option 'com.facebook.**' in line 2 of ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate in the file proguard-rules.pro, which classes will not be obfuscated, depending on the libraries you used in your project, for example:

https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro[enter link description here](http://Firebase)

Do not forget that you should not obfuscate your entities (request and response) of your web services

Comment: I've created a file named proguard-rules.pro and placed in in the app's folder in android studio (where the build.gradle is placed) , and added to the file :
`-dontwarn class com.facebook.** { *; }
-dontwarn class com.appsflyer.** { *; }
-dontwarn class org.joda.time.** { *; }`

It didn't help though unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

Try once like ***this*** :

```
-dontwarn com.facebook.**

-dontwarn com.appsflyer.**

-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
```